# RequireJS skip certain files during optimization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, gruntjs

I using requirejs, roptimizer, and grunt to run the tasks to optimize my angularjs application.

I'm building all my js's to one file for the time being using the following config:

```
({
    name: 'main',
    out: 'app.min.js',
    insertRequire: ['main'],
    wrap: true,
    separateCSS: true,
    mainConfigFile: 'main.js',
    preserveLicenseComments: false,
    optimize: 'uglify2',
    uglify2:{
        mangle: false
    },
    include: ['lib/require/require']
})
```

I also use a grunt task called [html2js](https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js) to compile all my HTML templates for angular to JavaScript to save downloads in production.

Problem is when I include these files in my build the optimizer messes them up and they no longer run correctly.  The way its setup I need them to be dropped in after angularjs but before anything else.

Including the files after my app.min.js file in the HTML page also does not work because I have to register the module like:  `app.requires.push('templates-main');`

Is it possible to have r-optimizer skip this file during optimization but still include it in the app.min.js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the require build config, add the filename followed by 'empty' like:

```
 compile: {
     options: {
         paths: {
             'templates':'empty:',
         }
      }
  }
```